# SSE with angular interceptors

Tags: angular, server-sent-events, angular-http-interceptors

How can we use HTTP interceptor to intercept SSE requests?

Below is my interceptor which is currently not intercepting my SSE requests.

```
@Injectable() export class HttpDateParserInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {

 intercept(request: HttpRequest<unknown>, next: HttpHandler): 
     Observable<HttpEvent<unknown>> {
       return next.handle(request).pipe(
         tap({
           next: (event: HttpEvent<any>) => {
            if (event instanceof HttpResponse) {
                  //some code
    
           }
          }
        })
       );
      }
```